# How to change a column to an IDENTITY column and preserve the data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I had a column which was IDENTITY(1,1). All rows had been numbered consecutively. I did not add or remove any rows. I removed the identity property on this column. Now, I want it back. I think i can reset it to identity with seed = biggest number in existing table.

Could any problems arise if I do this ?

Comment: I suggest trying it on a test db.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [MSDN SQL Server forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/04d69ee6-d4f5-4f8f-a115-d89f7bcbc032/how-to-alter-column-to-identity11?forum=transactsql) - You have 2 options:

1. Create a new table with identity & drop the existing table
2. Create a new column with identity & drop the existing column.

*But take special care when these columns have any constraints / relations

As stated in [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264478%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) about considerations for preserving data during deployment and schema Updates:

Changes to properties of an identity column on a table, such as the identity seed - **"Requires data motion"** and it can, in some cases, cause data loss during its execution of the synchronization.

The recommendation in this case: **"If the deployment or update script contains these types of changes, you might want to modify it manually to preserve the data"**