# Altering Column in SQL Server to auto_increment

Tags: sql-server-2008, alter

I am working on a project for which I got the database design by someone else. We have a table in which there is a column `ContractID (PK, bigint, not null)`

Now I am trying to alter this column with the following command

```
ALTER TABLE Contracts 
alter column ContractID bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

but it shows the following error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'AUTO_INCREMENT'.

Please someone help me out? Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957370/alter-table-adding-autoincrement-in-mysql

Comment: In SQL Server, it's called `IDENTITY` (not `AUTO_INCREMENT`), and you **cannot** add it to an existing column later on. You'll need to create a **new column** that has this attribute

Comment: You need `ALTER TABLE dbo.Contracts ADD NewContractID INT IDENTITY(1,1)`

Comment: I answered a similar question yesterday - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20177962/how-to-change-a-column-to-an-identity-column-and-preserve-the-data/20179192#20179192, be careful with data loss